# How do i enable cors policy / or request in react js with no access to the API?

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

Im using RapidApi to make som simple calls for fetching country data using axios. The API is paged in that the next response will have the URL for the next request. So basically i don't even have the URLs.

**Problem** i get the error which i have seen all over stack overflow about cors policy

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.hybridgfx.com/api/list-countries-states-cities?page=2' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I tried adding the line **"access-control-allow-origin": "*"** but that doesn't work and i still get the same error. When i click on the URL or just run it directly on the browser i get a bunch of data but when it is called in the code **it blows up** . Please help.

```
const fetchNextResults = async (url: string): Promise<FetchResponse> => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": MyKey,
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "countries-states-cities-dataset.p.rapidapi.com",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    },
  };
  const res: FetchResponse = await axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

  return res;
};
```

Comment: `access-control-allow-origin` is not a request header, but a response header. You can safely drop it from your request.

Comment: @jub0bs after dropping it how do i get rid of the error

Comment: You need to configure the server for CORS, if you control it. But one thing's for sure: adding `access-control-allow-origin` never helps.

Comment: @jub0bs i just figured that out. But i don't control the server, is there anything i can do?

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid you won't be able to consume the API in question from the browser. You'll have to proxy those requests through your backend.

Comment: Just to be more precise: I meant that adding `access-control-allow-origin` to a request never helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a request throw the CORS proxy.
[List of proxies](https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347).

```
url: <proxy url>/<my url>
```

Or [create your own](https://dev.to/imiebogodson/fixing-the-cors-error-by-hosting-your-own-proxy-on-heroku-3lcb).

Comment: Example in code